# How to boot to Windows if grub is broken and BIOS won't open?

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, mbr

I recently accidentally deleted my Ubuntu partition. When I rebooted the computer, I got the dreaded `grub rescue>` prompt. I thought, "simple fix, boot an ubuntu CD and add a new MBR". However, my BIOS will somehow not let me access *any* menus with any keys specified by my PC manufacturer (MSI). I think this is something to do with a fast boot mode or something, because I don't see a MSI logo on boot, so it may be skipping POST.

I need a way to boot an Ubuntu LiveCD from grub or to boot the Windows partition. Nothing I have tried have worked. I tried listing the contents of all the drives provided by "ls", but GRUB can't read any of them.

Comment: Did you try the del key, immediately on powerup?

Comment: Yes, many times. I tried loads of keys. Holding, mashing, single press, nothing worked.

Comment: Worst case scenario, I may have to buy a USB hdd enclosure and replace the MBR with another computer.

Comment: When I had a Windows XP disk in the drive but did not press anything, it would find the Windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

There are different combinations on different BIOS versions:

- AMI [DEL]-Key after boot
- Award [CTRL][ALT][ESC] or [DEL].
- Phoenix [CTRL][ALT][ESC] or [CTRL][ALT][S] or [CTRL][ALT][Insert]
- Or [F2]

Maybe you try these combinations to start your bios.

Comment: I'm not seeing any MSI logo or BIOS info prompt on startup; as I said maybe it is locked into some strange fast boot that doesn't check for keypresses properly? I tried you suggestions and many more.

Comment: Maybe I should open it up and remove the CMOS battery for a bit; would that help? It would reset the BIOS settings, so maybe it would allow me in.